# Google Cloud VM Instance is not authorized with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have dist-upgraded my Debian VM instance to current version after which I have re-installed the google cloud host environment. This is the state of google-related services:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep google
google-cloud-ops-agent-diagnostics.service             enabled         enabled
google-cloud-ops-agent-fluent-bit.service              static          -
google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service static          -
google-cloud-ops-agent.service                         enabled         enabled
google-guest-agent.service                             enabled         enabled
google-osconfig-agent.service                          enabled         enabled
google-oslogin-cache.service                           static          -
google-shutdown-scripts.service                        enabled         enabled
google-startup-scripts.service                         enabled         enabled
google-oslogin-cache.timer                             enabled         enabled
```

I cannot see any errors with them in system logs. My `gcloud config list` looks like:

```
[core]
account = my-project-id-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = my-project

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

Everything *seems to be fine*, and yet I cannot access any gcloud resources, eg.

```
# gcloud compute instances list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

I have some other instance, which was not upgraded. The commands above give the same result, but the `gcloud compute instances list` works correctly. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is undefined on both instances and none of the instances has `$HOME/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` file.

How can I authorize the service account so that it is usable on the broken instance?

Comment: Is your VM GCP compute instance?

Comment: @Vojtech doing a dist-upgrade should not be deleting files from your file system, unless there is some bug. If it's a compute instance as asked by `guillaume blaquiere` I have replicated it by creating a new VM, installing gcloud sdk and gcloud cli, then I performed a dist upgrage. Still, I'm able to fetch instance list from the project. can you check and inform if these are the steps you are also following or need to add something here..

Comment: It is a compute instance and the packages were indeed removed. I had to add gcloud apt repositories for the new distro (the apt source was for old distro) and re-install them manually.

Comment: Note that I had stretch and upgraded to bullseye. I don't know how it broke, but I certainly need to find a way to fix it.

Comment: @Vojtěch you can try `sudo apt --fix-missing update` and `sudo apt-get update -f` commands for fixing broken packages in linux.

Comment: I have no missing or broken packages. Everything seems to be fine with the system.

Comment: @Vojtěch previously you said that it broke can you explain what has broken like the upgrade process or packages. you are saying that packages are not broken, so can you let us know what fix you are looking for..?

Comment: By "broken instance" I just mean the instance, that is not authorized to `gcloud`. Please read my question carefully, especially "Everything seems to be fine, and yet I cannot access any gcloud resources, eg."

Comment: @Vojtěch Okay after reinstalling the gcloud packages is it working for you..?

Comment: No it doesn't work and everything seems to be installed correctly.